# has many implement in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I find myself starting with laravel and I need a little help from the following:
I have a one-to-many relationship between: a product can have multiple images at the same time, an image belongs to a product. code:

Product:

```
class Product extends Model
{
  public function images(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
  }
}
```

Image:

```
class Image extends Model
{
  public function product(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
  }
}
```

Now to show the View I want to show only the first image of each product, I do this in the controller:

```
public function index()
{
  $products = Product::all();
  $products = Product::join('images', 'products.id', '=', 'images.id')->select('products.id','products.denomination_prod','products.description','pooducts.price','images.path')
  ->get();

  return view('products.products', compact('products'));
}
```

Now you could tell me if this is done correctly. That is I am respecting the standards of good structure?.
I hope you can help me; perhaps a silly question for many but they are my first steps with this excellent framework and would like to learn it the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `join()`. You can just use the declared relationship:

```
$products = Product::with('images')->get();
```

and then you are going to have an images collection per product. Afterwards you can do whatever you like with each product's images collection. A simple loop might be useful:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <img src="{{asset($product->images->first())}}" />
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Since you have just started your flight with Laravel apart from the Eloquent chapter you should also check the [collections chapter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections)